# How to autostart multiple commands within one?

Tags: linux, boot

I want to autostart a program with multiple commands within one.

Here are my 3 separate commands:

```
sleep 3s
cd /home/user/programdir/lpfw/
gksudo ./lpfwpygui
```

My command is `sleep 3s;cd /home/user/programdir/lpfw/;gksudo ./lpfwpygui`.

It works fine if run manually from terminal, but I can't get it to work from autostart entry.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a script with your commands and running the script from the autostart entry:

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 3s
cd /home/user/programdir/lpfw
gksudo ./lpfwpygui
```

You should also try sleeping for longer, 3s may not be enough for the Desktop Environment to finish loading and that could cause problems since you are using gksudo.

Comment: thanks for replying; one thing is the program doesn't run if gksudo /home/user/programdir/lpfw/lpfwpygui but will run after cd to parent dir and then gksudo ./ that's weird

Comment: @user177480, OK, changed the script. So, does it work if your autostart entry calls the script? Does it work if you increase the sleep time?

Comment: yes all good thanks a lot; do you have any idea why it doesn't work if i type "gksudo /path/script" while it works if i cd first and then gksudo?

Comment: @user177480, not really no. Some kind of security feature probably but I don't know. Also, while thanks are always appreciated, the standard way of thanking people on the stackexchange network is to upvote and/or accept their answer (the check mark to the left of an answer).

Comment: done ! but i can't upvote as it requires 15 reputation i have only 8 :(, wish i could, sorry

Answer (score 1):

In Autostart, multiple commands can run in sequence if a shell executes them:

```
Exec=bash -c "cmd1 ; cmd2 ; cmd3"
```

Or in your case:

```
Exec=bash -c "sleep 3s;cd /home/user/programdir/lpfw/;gksudo ./lpfwpygui"
```

This likely also works with other shells than bash, but with other syntax.